# Botan library - fastest digital signature verification

Tags: c++, windows, performance, botan

I am looking for the fastest algorithm, where I can verify a digital signature of a blob. The algorithm shouldn't necessarily be cryptographically secure, just make sure that it's not trivially fakable. Signing time neither counts in my case.

Any suggestions?
Also if possible, can you tell me what modules of botan do I need to use? (In order to only include them in my build!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out that botan library has a cli. If you target this via `--build-targets="static,cli"` you can measure speed of different algorithms on your machine. Of course it will be specific to your computer, but for me this information was enough.

You can check out different options of the botan cli at:
https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/cli.html